# Starting a Django virtual environment in Grunt

Tags: django, gruntjs, virtualenv

Coming from a JS / Node development background, I like to use Grunt for a lot of my automation. For a recent project I picked up some baby Django, to get a feel for how it operated, but still wanted to integrate Grunt for some of my workflow.

I am currently starting my Django server via Grunt, using the spawn-shell module. This works just fine, but I am also using a virtualenv setup, and would as well like to start that up via Grunt.

The command I am using to start the virtual enviornment is:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Which works just fine from the terminal command line as is. However, executing this command from either grunt shell or grunt exec does nothing. I get no errors from Grunt (it says running, then done without errors), but nothing gets started.

The grunt exec command is as follows:

```
exec: {
  start: {
    cmd: function() {
      return "source ./venv/bin/activate";
    }
  }
}
```

And the shell command is:

shell: {

```
  start: {
    command: 'source ./venv/bin/activate',
    options: {
      stdout: true
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? Or is it not possible, and I should just resort to entering the command manually at start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when trying to get other tooling to launch django while using a virtualenv the normal thing is to perform both of the following in one command :

1. activate the virtualenv
2. run the command you want.

so this ends up being :

`. ${VIRTUALENVHOME}/bin/activate && ${PROJECTROOT}/manage.py runserver 0:8000`

This is pretty much how it's done with Fabric, Ansible and any other automation tool.

edit: of course you'd be supplying the values for the variables `VIRTUALENVHOME` and `PROJECTROOT`

Comment: I don't like multi-commands line, but your solution works great!

Comment: @MateuszJagiełło the reason why you have to do it this way is because all these tools will launch new shell processes for each command. So while in one process your virtualenv was actually activated, in the next it was not. Chaining them together like this means it's still in the same process.